# How to extract word before and after specified character?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anybody help me how to return word before and after specified character in excel
this is word i have...
the specified character is

> #

```
14011242105#23140973#SAKTI AHMAD SYAHRONI# # # #BEKASI#10011994#L#T#KTP#3275050110940012# #10012015#667054753432000#HJ SITI SALAMAH#KP RAWA PANJANG. RT.01/04#KABUPATEN BEKASI# #KP RAWA PANJANG. RT.01/04#KABUPATEN BEKASI# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #01-APR-14# # #02871900858#152791162
```

thank you!

Comment: What is the specified character? Can you give an example of the result you want?

Comment: sorry i forget to write that...specified char '#'

Comment: Ok, so are you looking to get words "14011242105", "23140973", "SAKTI AHMAD SYAHRONI", " " etc. from this string? Or is white space a delimiter too?

Comment: yes just words "14011242105", "23140973", "SAKTI AHMAD SYAHRONI", " " etc

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to select the cells that contain your string then use Text to Columns:

**Data** tab > **Data** Tools group > **Text to Columns**

Select **Delimited** > **Next**

Check the box **Other** and type **#** in the box

Hit **Next**. You may want to change some of the columns to **Text** here, specifically those that contain numbers.

Hit **Finish**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBSTITUTE function as under"
If the text what you are quoting is in Cell A1 then in Cell A2 type the formula:
= SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#"," ")
You will get in cell A2 the names and numbers without hash symbol